# Bash == not found

Tags: bash, if-statement, string-comparison

I have a small bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$@" == "pull" ]]
then
    # stuff 
elif [[ "$@" == "push" ]]
then
   # stuff
else
    echo "Command not recognised"
fi
```

it's located in /usr/bin/local and I made it executable. However whenever I run it I get `script:1: == not found`

Any ideas?

This is macOS if that matters.

Comment: in the prompt: zsh: `bad pattern: [[`

Comment: Fix the typo in your original question (missing space before the second `==`), add what arguments you are calling it with. Are you calling it with bash or zsh?

Comment: I'm calling it as a global script, as it's in /usr/local/bin. ZSH is my prompt, however the first line of the script `#!/bin/bash` should set the env to bash when the script executes?

Comment: It seems to work for me. Maybe it's another downstream function call that's causing the error?

Comment: What's in `# stuff`? can you _copy and paste exactly_ what your script is?

Comment: I'm not sure @leekaiinthesky I don't see anything else that should affect it?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf it's ssh'in to a dev box, but that isn't where the error is taking place. I could change both to echo out a string and the error doesn't change.

Comment: In that case, please post the version that echoes out a string and still produces the error. :)

Comment: @melpomene: no, unlikely.

Comment: @melpomene: "" is not the same as no argument.

Comment: @leekaiinthesky There is no `""` in that code, only `"$@"`.

Comment: @melpomene: irrelevant, this is `[[`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Ah. You're right. I retract my guess.

Comment: `"$@"` doesn't make sense in this context. It expands to an arbitrary number of words, whereas the left hand side of a comparison can only be exactly one value.

Comment: That said, to figure out *exactly* what's going on here, it would be helpful to run `bash -x yourscript` -- and to run your original, unredacted code through http://shellcheck.net/. But fix the inappropriate use of `"$@"` regardless.

Comment: BTW, replace `# stuff` with `: stuff` or `: # stuff` -- that way this isn't a syntax error for not having any commands between the `then` and `elif`, or later the `then` and `else`.

Comment: Even in bash's `[[ ]]`, by the way, it's *still* a better practice to use `=` than `==` -- that way you aren't forming habits that'll lead you to write buggy code for other shells or test commands.

Comment: The biggest problem with this question, though, is that **you didn't test the code included in it to reproduce the same problem you're asking about** -- if you'd tested it, you would have noted the unrelated syntax errors (due to the missing body contents in the test conditions), and fixed the syntax errors reproduced thereby.

Comment: The error occurs on line 1... It doesn't matter if there are syntax errors later on if the script doesn't even get past line 1 @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @AdamJarvis, not true: Compound commands (like `if`) are parsed in full before any part of them is executed.

Comment: @AdamJarvis, **actually try** copying-and-pasting the code in your StackOverflow question into a new file, and running that file (with `bash -x yourfile`). I did, and it gives the syntax error I described, not the `== not found` given in the question.

Comment: ...see also your code running at http://ideone.com/RMi57w, and its output.

Comment: Also, see a version with the immediate syntax error corrected (and a hardcoded command line of `pull "second arg" "third arg"`) running at http://ideone.com/heo7ms. It doesn't do what you *want* because of the use of `"$@"`, but it also doesn't result in the `== not found` error you're claiming in the question. If you can come up with an edit that *does* result in that exact error, I'll be very interested to see it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use `[[`, not defined by POSIX. Instead use `[`
2. Don't use `==`, use `=`
3. Don't use `$@`, use `$1`
4. Don't use double quotes in this situation for `pull` and `push`, matter of fact don't use them at all
5. Don't use Bash when sh will do

Updated script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = pull ]
then
  # stuff 
elif [ "$1" = push ]
then
 # stuff
else
  echo 'Command not recognised'
fi
```

Comment: You don't know if `# stuff` doesn't use bash features.

Comment: Perfect, works as intended. Still, wish I knew why Bash wasn't working?

Comment: Couldn't the whole thing be done as `case "$1" in pull) ...;; push) ...;; *) ...;; esac`?

Comment: @melpomene: of course, that would be _the_ idiomatic way.

Comment: @AdamJarvis, ...bash *would* work, if you used it with the code in Steven's answer. :)

Comment: Although the quotes around `pull` and `push` aren't *necessary*, there's no reason to recommend against using them.

Comment: @StevePenny . Hmm. I guess I find your statement ambiguous AND you have included dbl-quotes around `"$1"` as I would recommend. so the phrase "don't use them at all" may make sense, but I don't see it. However I'm will to let this rest of you are. Yours is a perfectly workable answer. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with bash as your interpreter, your only issue is with your uses of `"$@"`, which in tests like bash's `[[` and POSIX's `[` and `test`, expands to all arguments surrounded by quotes (just like `"$*"`).  You probably want `"$1"` to test just the first argument.

You can also consider using a `case` (switch) statement:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
  ( pull )  echo "you said pull" ;;
  ( push )  echo "you said push" ;;
  (  *  )   echo "Command '$1' is not recognised" ;;
esac
```

(The above code will work in bash, sh, and zsh.  I assume you still require bash due to other aspects of your code.)

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce or explain the `== not found` output the OP reports?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy – No, I cannot reproduce that with Bash 4.4.5, Bash 4.0.42, ksh 93u+, or zsh 5.3.  Dash and friends will of course complain about the bashisms first. I'm also confused by the reporter's ability to execute the program given the invalid shebang, which is to say I have no idea what shell is actually being used.  csh and tcsh will complain about an illegal variable name first (also, [don't use those](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)!)

Comment: Where does it say `bash` is not correctly installed? The *script* is in `/usr/local/bin`, but there is nothing wrong with the shebang.

Comment: Also, `"$@"` is *not* expanded to multiple words inside `[[`, because word-splitting is suppressed for parameter expansions. Here, `"$@"` and `$*` would behave identically.

Comment: @chepner – interesting, I did not know that. I guess that's why I didn't see any errors.  I've revised my answer.